# Can an M.2 to USB adapter support M type but not B+M type?

Tags: ssd, sata, m.2

It seems to me that the B type SSD supports only SATA and the M type SSD only supports PCIe, and B+M SSD supports both SATA and PCIe. Now, there is an M.2 to USB adapter that says that it only supports the M type, not B+M type. Is that possible? Physically, an B+M type SSD should fit into the adapter's socket, and if so, isn't all that the adapter has to is just ignoring the B type lanes?

[image]

Comment: What model is the adapter?

Comment: The physical connection is independent of the actual support provided by the chipset/controller. Manufacturers installing a "B+M" slot but only supporting SATA or NVMe, not both. So, by only supporting the "M type", according to your description, what they're actually saying is the adapter is for NVMe only.